# How to find out which Java classes are missing in GWT (client side)?

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to import a Java library into a GWT project.

Since the client-side of GWT does not have access to the whole Java API, some classes cannot be found.

Unfortunately, the compiler does not complain because the J2EE package is included into the project (for the server side code).

Now, how can I find out which Java classes, my library requires, are missing on client-side?
Is there a list out there or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This link [GWT JRE Emulation Reference](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) shows the list of the classes you can use on the client side. There are out there client libraries to add missing widgets or features to the out-of-the-box API.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for that list! That already helps me a lot.

Is there a way though to automatically retrieve a list of the packages that are being used by my library but aren't included on the client-side of GWT?

Going through each java file and checking for each package if it exists or not is no very efficient.