# Using Packages and Classes from JDK in GWT Project

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out which Java classes are missing in GWT (client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638540/how-to-find-out-which-java-classes-are-missing-in-gwt-client-side)

Help, prompt me which packages and classes from JDK (java.*) I can use in GWT web project and which I can't use?

Answer (score 3):

[JRE Emulation Reference](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) lists packages and classes from JDK - subset of the Java runtime library supported by GWT.

Note that subset may depend on particular version of GWT that you use - ie you might need to find *JRE Emulation Reference* doc that matches your version of GWT.

Comment: oh, thanks for link, it's useful

Comment: @Farrukhjon glad to be of help. Do you know by the way that at Stack Overflow, you can "accept" answers? Here is a screen shot on how to do that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png